# Aggregate results in time series forecasting

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm working on time series forecasting with some sales data, with no exogenous variables, only sales per day.

After some analysis, including seasonal decompose, plot autocorrelation and parcial autocorrelation, etc. I've tried some models, including ARIMA (with pmdarima) as baseline and some others like LSTM and adaBoostRegressor.

All of them work reasonably good with other datasets, but with my data all of them performs very poorly. 
Anyway the daily data looks very random, but if I predict for example a month, the rate between all the (daly) predictions aggregated and all the (daly) real values aggregated looks very close to 0.

My question is:

- Does make any sense to predict daly data and then aggregate by week, or month or quarter, etc.?

For example, if I want to predict 1 week, first predict daly data for 7 days and then aggregate all.

My report for baseline model AUTOARIMA looks like this (every new prediction is made with previous predictions, not all at once over test data):

[image]

As you can see, the aggregated results for one month are very close, so for me makes sense to make this prediction since I don't care about daly sales but we are interested in weekly or monthly predictions.

Thanks a lot